# Checking bit state of lpt port binary

Tags: c#, binary, lpt

I've part of code which is checking input pins of lpt port, but using decimal values:

```
while (PortAccess.Input(889) == 120)
```

How to use this instruction with binary values?

for example while bit 3 of 00100100 is 0 then do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i've done this, because tafa solution wasn't working and i couldn't make it work:

```
   var PortValue = Convert.ToString(PortAccess.Input(889), 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
   PortV.Text = PortValue;
   while (PortV.Text[3].ToString() == "1")
   {
   //some code
   }
```

It's probably not good solution, but it's working ;)

Answer (score 1):

See [Convert.ToInt32(string value, int fromBase)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx)

```
while((value & Convert.ToInt32("00000100", 2)) == 0)
```

Or since we know the third bit is for (2^2)

```
while((value & 0x0004) == 0)
```

is also a clear enough piece of code, I guess.

Comment: "Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool' :(    int newPortValue = PortAccess.Input(889);
            if (newPortValue & 0x0004==0)

Comment: Sorry, the problem is about operator precedence, I am reflecting this issue to my answer. Please notice the parentheses added.